# Matplotlib and gevent monkey patching

Tags: matplotlib, thread-safety, gevent, monkeypatching, ui-thread

I would like to understand how gevent monkey patching affects matplotlib.

I am displaying a set of images in a grid using matplotlib's subplots.
This is straightforeward, but the images are remotely stored
and the grid is large enough to make it slow.

Normally the simplest way to address this would be using gevent monkey patching, but I am concerned about how this interacts with matplotlib.

Matplotlib is not threadsafe, but gevent monkey patching should make everything single threaded, turning the matplotlib event queue into another coroutine. I am not completely sure that is enough though.

The following code works without any detectable problems

```
import gevent
from gevent import pool
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
g = pool.Group()

from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cytoolz as tlz
import sys
from skimage import io

clusters = ... # nested list of URLs

R = max(map(len, clusters)
C = len(clusters)

def urlshow(ax, url):
    ax.axis("off")
    img = io.imread(url)
    ax.imshow(img)

def urlsubplot(fig, r, c, url):
  try:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(R, C, c + C*r + 1)
    urlshow(ax, url)
  except e:
    print >>sys.stderr, e

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, top=1.0, bottom=0.3, left=0, right=1.0)
for i, cl  in enumerate(clusters):
    for j, url in enumerate(cl):
        g.spawn(urlsubplot, fig, j, i, np.random.choice(url))

g.join()

fig.show()
```

but I would like to know if it is sound and what is needed if not.